# Как сделать словарь из списка?

Tags: python, словари

Есть список из двух элементов, выглядит вот так:

```
['word', 10]
```

Как из него сделать словарь, что бы первый элемент, записался, как `key`, а второй, как `value {'word':10}`?

Comment: Эмм, а зачем? Если по простому - создать словарь, добавить в нем новую запись, где ключ = array[0], значение - array[1]. Однако Ваша задача мне совсем не понятна.

Comment: Посмотри ответ на аналогичный вопрос:
[Convert a list to a dictionary in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4576128/3134058)

Comment: Эмм, а зачем? Если по простому - создать словарь, добавить в нем новую запись, где ключ = array[0], значение - array[1]. Однако Ваша задача мне совсем не понятна. – Sleeeper 47 минут назад   Ну вот такое у меня домашнее задание. Вроде просто, а не понимаю.

Comment: @vanzhiganov спасибо громадное! Вот оно!    ls = ['a', 'b']
dict([ls])
>>> {'a':'b'}

Answer (score 5):

Вопрос не совем ясен, поэтому отвечу так, чтобы покрыть все варианты.
пусть `input = ['word', 10]`

Если вы хотите создать словарь {'word':10} , то вам следует написать:
`result = dict([input])`

Если же всё же {'word':['word', 10]} , то:
`new_input = [input[0],input]
result = dict([new_input])`

Comment: Osipov Большое спасибо! dict([input]) то, что надо!